# Visual Intuitive for Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function with no singularities (an entire function) and $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$. Then 
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$$

But I'm failing to understand this visually. My understanding is that a line integral is essentially the area of the "curtain" formed between the curve and the plane, but that notion doesn't really work here since the complex function has both a real and imaginary output. Is there some intuitive, visual, easy to understand way to see why this integral is always zero? Of course I can see a proof with symbolic mathematics, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: Possibly worth a read: https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~allenam/IntuitiveResidues.pdf

Comment: Would it help to think of it as analogous to conservative vector fields, they need to have zero curl, and analytic functions need to obey the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: In one-variable Calculus, if $\int f\,dx=F(x)+C$, then $\int_a^b f\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$, so if $F(a)=F(b)$, then that definite integral is zero. Similarly, $\int_{\gamma}f\,dz$ is the difference in the values of $F(z)$ at the two ends of the curve $\gamma$. If it's a closed curve, that difference is zero.

Comment: I dont think that there is a "visual" proof for line integrals, maybe something related to the homotopy of a closed curve to a point for simply connected subsets, however this require some algebra. But a non-visual argument could be that $\int_a ^a f=0$

Comment: "My understanding is that a line integral is essentially the area of the "curtain" formed between the curve and the plane": That makes very little sense to me. Possibly I'm just missing the point, or possibly your understanding needs to be revised...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, a similar statement is made on the Wikipedia article for a Line Integral: "The line integral of f would be the area of the "curtain" created when the points of the surface that are directly over C [the curve] are carved out." I was simply wondering if there is a corresponding analogue for analytic functions with domains in $\mathbb{C}$, perhaps in some way relating to the separated real and complex parts of f.

Comment: In the context where they say that in the Wikipedia article $f$ is _real-valued_.